# How to plot the scatter chart by counting employee numbers using python

Tags: python, group-by, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataset like below:

```
Employee_No    Hire_Date    Status
000001         01/23/2019    T
000002         01/28/2019    A
000003         02/02/2019    A
000004         02/06/2019    A
000005         02/08/2019    T
```

I would like to plot by using seaborn to make a chart like this:
[image]

I would like the X-axis to be the hire date grouped by Month. The Y-axis to be the count of employees. The dots should be colored by status(whether they are active or terminated).

I tried:

```
sns.scatterplot(x = 'Hire_Date', y = 'employee_No', hue = 'target', data = workdata1)
```

I don't know how to execute the counting function and group the x data into the month.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm still unsure I understand how your data would be shown, what the count of employees should be on Y-axis? Can draw some kind of example by hand to understand your desired output based on some data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using grouping in pandas. Import the libraries.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
```

Then import your data into a dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

    Employee_No     Hire_Date   Status
0   1   1/23/2019   T
1   2   1/28/2019   A
2   3   2/2/2019    A
3   4   2/6/2019    A
4   5   2/8/2019    T
5   6   3/1/2019    A
6   7   3/7/2019    A
7   8   3/15/2019   T
8   9   4/18/2019   A
9   10  4/29/2019   T
```

Make sure to change the date column type to datetime with

```
df['Hire_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hire_Date'])
```

It is important to have a tidy dataframe to be able to use seaborn scatterplot, so let's add a year and month columns.

```
df['year']= df['Hire_Date'].map(lambda x: x.year)
df['month'] = df['Hire_Date'].map(lambda x: x.month)
```

Now, if you group by month and status you get the terminated and active employees for each month

```
df.groupby(["month","Status"]).count().Employee_No

month  Status  Employee_No Count
1      A         1
       T         1
2      A         2
       T         1
3      A         2
       T         1
4      A         1
       T         1
```

To be able to use scatterplot in sns reset the index of the group operation

```
df_tidy = df.groupby(["month","Status"]).count().reset_index()
```

And now use scatterplot:

```
sns.scatterplot(x = 'month', y = 'Employee_No', hue='Status', data = df.tidy)
```

[image: Scatter plot of count of employees per status]